# Finding the singular point of the solution to $y'-\left(\tfrac{6}{17}\sin x\right)y=\tfrac{5}{32} x^4 y^2, \; y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The solution to
>   $$y'-\left(\tfrac{6}{17}\sin x\right)y=\tfrac{5}{32} x^4 y^2, \qquad y(0)=1$$
>   has a singular point at $x=a$. Find $a$. (Hint: find $y(x)$ when $y\gg 1$.)

I think this is a Bernoulli equation, and setting $u=y^{-1}$, then substituting into the equation, I get
$$u' + \left(\tfrac{6}{17}\sin x\right)u = \tfrac{-5}{32}x^4$$
I don’t know where to go from here.
Is there any way to solve the problem?
thanks a lot!

Comment: a explicit solution is not possible

Comment: no explicit solution?that's so terrible, is there any  way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use the hint,when y>>1,u->0

then i got:
$du/dx=-5x^4/32$

solve for u and y,with y(0)=1

$y=1/(1-5/32*x^4)$,

for singular point,$1-5/32*x^4=0$=>x=2